# prevent 404 when using history.pushState

Tags: javascript

I'm using `history.pushState()` to display a different URL in the browser bar. However, the URL that is displayed does not actually exist. Therefore, if the user goes to a different page and then comes back, it will get a 404. Is there a way I can prevent this, maybe with htaccess?

Comment: If you're trying to use `history.pushState()` to route your web app as a SPA, I highly recommend checking out an existing API that helps do this for you. [Backbone](http://backbonejs.org/) is a great and simple one that I've used before — [check out it's router](http://backbonejs.org/#Router)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main use for `history.pushState` is for you to keep track of the state of the page in your JavaScript application, so that your user can save that URL to get to that exact page some time in the future.

You can solve that problem by actually implementing the route you are pushing in the browser.

It could either be by server side or client side, just so you can ensure a good user experience.